# Getting all nested children within xml tag in python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have an xml.etree.ElementTree object with the following content.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <c>
   <winforms>
    <type-conversion>
     <opacity>
     </opacity>
    </type-conversion>
   </winforms>
  </c>
 </body>
</html>
<html>
 <body>
  <css>
   <css3>
    <internet-explorer-7>
    </internet-explorer-7>
   </css3>
  </css>
 </body>
</html>
<html>
 <body>
  <c>
   <code-generation>
    <j>
     <visualj>
     </visualj>
    </j>
   </code-generation>
  </c>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to get all the tags within each `body` tag pair. 
For example, The output I want for the above example is:

```
c, winforms, type-conversion, opactiy
css, css3, internet-explorer-7
c, code-generation,j, visualj
```

How do I do this is in python using either BeautifulSoup or The ElementTree XML API?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I'm unable to code. The xml data mentioned above is in the form of an  xml.etree.ElementTree object. I wanted to know if there was a function `xmltreeobject.functionName()` which would return all the nested child nodes for a given root node.

Comment: This is not a valid xml document, looks like multiple documents combined, so presumably there is an outer tag that wraps all these xml docs. You are probably looking for `ElementTree.findall()` which takes a path to find all the the elements, e.g. `root.findall('html/body')` or `root.findall('.//body')` [any depth] would return all the `body` tags (assuming a wrapping tag for all the xml docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, XML specification allows only one root element in a document. If that is your actual XML, then you need to wrap it with a temporary root element before parsing.

Now, having a well-formed XML you can use `xml.etree` for parsing, and use simple XPath expression `.//body//*` to query all elements, either direct child or nested, within `<body>` elements :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

raw = '''xml string as posted in the question'''
root = et.fromstring('<root>'+raw+'</root>')

target_elements = root.findall('.//body/*')

result = [t.tag for t in target_elements]
print result
# output :
# ['c', 'winforms', 'type-conversion', 'opacity', 'css', 'css3', 'internet-explorer-7', 'c', 'code-generation', 'j', 'visualj']
```